# Search a list of objects for any and all matches

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a `List<T>` of `User` instances, and I need to do a search over all the fields in the `User`.

What's the most efficient way of doing this?

This is the definition of my `User` class:

```
public class User
{
    public String SamAccountName { get; set; }
    public String EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public String WorkPhone { get; set; }
    public String MobilePhone { get; set; }
    public String Office { get; set; }
}
```

I need to search for to see if the value of "Tom" is contained in any of the strings in any of the fields and return a new `List<T>` with only the instances that match that criteria.

I'd like to do this with LINQ but don't know how.  How can I do this?

Comment: give an example of what `Tom` would look like in the email address what if you have multiple `Tom's`..? please be a bit more specific on what you are looking for

Comment: The list contains all users within Active Directory, which is displayed to the user (in a repeater). I need to allow the users to do a free-form search over the users. So yes, Tom wouldn't apply for phone number, but it might be in name, or email...I could always filter which fields to search over based on the input (numeric will search the phone numbers, text all the other fields).        The User class I shared is missing some fields...

Comment: I am very familiar with AD I would suggest that you do a search on the samAccount or Display Name and from there you can check the individual things like there mail and things of that nature.. you Phone number would not need to be a part of that search.. also depending on how you are searching AD I would suggest maybe using a Hashtable and Hashfields to store what it is you need.. if you are really wanting a List<t> I would do List<Dictionary<object,string>> just some ideas

Comment: DJ Kraze, I'm getting all the users in a List and binding the list to my repeater. The user at first sees all the employees. They can then search via a text box, and they want the ability to search over all displayed fields, including phone number. My plan is to get the results into a new List and bind that to the repeater.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have an [`IEnumerable<User>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx), you could do this:

```
// Query for "Tom" being contained in any of the fields.
var query =
    from user in users
    where
        (user.SamAccountName != null && user.SamAccountName.Contains("Tom")) ||
        (user.EmailAddress != null && user.EmailAddress.Contains("Tom")) ||
        (user.WorkPhone != null && user.WorkPhone.Contains("Tom")) ||
        (user.MobilePhone != null && user.MobilePhone.Contains("Tom")) ||
        (user.Office != null && user.Office.Contains("Tom"))
    select user;
```

Note, the check for `null` is important in the event that any of these fields is null, otherwise, when you call the [`Contains` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) on the [`String` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) it will throw a [`NullReferenceException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx) as there's no string to make the call to `Contains` on.

The [`where` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311043.aspx) simply maps to the [`Where` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) on the [`Enumerable` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) (make sure to have a `using System.Linq;` declaration so the extension methods are recognized by the compiler).

If you feel the null check is excessive and/or repetitive, you could whittle down your code like so:

```
// Generate your predicate.
Func<string, bool> checkContainsTom = s => s != null && s.Contains("Tom");

// Query.
var query =
    from user in users
    where
        checkContainsTom(user.SamAccountName) ||
        checkContainsTom(user.EmailAddress) ||
        checkContainsTom(user.WorkPhone) ||
        checkContainsTom(user.MobilePhone) ||
        checkContainsTom(user.Office)
    select user;
```

This is slightly better, as you're encapsulating the redundant logic; if the logic changes, you only have to change it in one place and it will be applied to all the checks.  Feel free to substitute the [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) with a function if you want.

You can then enumerate through `query` with a [`foreach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) if you want to use [deferred execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633.aspx).  If you need it in a materialized list (like a [`List<User>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)), then you just call the [`ToList` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) on the `Enumerable` class, like so:

```
 IList<User> materializedResults = query.ToList();
```

Comment: lazyberezovsky the .Contains should be sufficient unless there are some other conditions that would cause casperOne's logic to fail what he has written as an answer should work out just fine if he changes it to Contains

Comment: @DJKRAZE Fixed, and added a null check, since we don't know if it's going to be null or not.  Something no other answer here has taken into consideration.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't pretty, but it should work:

```
users.Where(u => u.SamAccountName.Contains("Tom") ||
                 u.EmaildAddress.Contains("Tom") ||
                 u.WorkPhone.Contains("Tom") ||
                 u.MobilePhone.Contains("Tom") ||
                 u.Office.Contains("Tom"));
```

Although, I have to say, I don't understand why you'd need to search for the string "Tom" inside of the phone numbers.

Comment: Hey, if you want to make it uglier you can always throw reflection in there to grab all the properties and check their values using the `Any` extension.

Comment: @JoelEtherton - I was really hoping that I wouldn't have to go there.

Comment: The call to `.Contains` will fail in certain cases.  If any of the fields are null, it will throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: I wouldn't need to search for "Tom" in phone, but I would need to search the Phone field if a number is input.

Answer (score 3):

Copy one generic extension method in some static class:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> WhereAtLeastOneProperty<T, PropertyType>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Predicate<PropertyType> predicate)
    {            
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.CanRead && prop.PropertyType == typeof(PropertyType)).ToArray();
        return source.Where(item => properties.Any(prop => PropertySatisfiesPredicate(predicate, item, prop)));
    }

    private static bool PropertySatisfiesPredicate<T, PropertyType>(Predicate<PropertyType> predicate, T item, System.Reflection.PropertyInfo prop)
    {
        try
        {
            return predicate((PropertyType)prop.GetValue(item));
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And then you just call:

```
var usersList = new List<User>();
var filteredUsersList = usersList.WhereAtLeastOneProperty((string s) => s.Contains("Tom")).ToList();
```

Or with some other lambda fitting your needs better. e.g.

```
.WhereAtLeastOneProperty((string s) => s=="Tom")
```

Comment: I am sorry, I didnt notice the word efficient at the first time. This is definitely slower, you can easily measure how much in your specific case.

Comment: It will throw an exception in the inner method, which is in a try/catch blok. Read the code please. And, of course, the null check can be also propagated into the lambda method, like this:

Comment: WhereAtLeastOneProperty((string s) => s!=null && s.Contains("Tom"))

Comment: Thanks for the answer, nice example.
I think it will be better to include points from your comments into the answer because they are quite important and it's very convenient when answer is full and self-contained.

Comment: +1 Because in my case, I'm trying to add a generic search feature regardless of the type I'm trying to search.  It's inefficient, but simple.